# Filter JSON on the command line

Tags: json, command-line-interface

I want to filter JSON on the command line.

Task: print the "name" of each dictionary in the json list.

Example json:

```
[
   {
      "id":"d963984c-1075-4d25-8cd0-eae9a7e2d130",
      "extra":{
         "foo":false,
         "bar":null
      },
      "created_at":"2020-05-06T15:31:59Z",
      "name":"NAME1"
   },
   {
      "id":"ee63984c-1075-4d25-8cd0-eae9a7e2d1xx",
      "name":"NAME2"
   }
]
```

Desired output:

```
NAME1
NAME2
```

This script would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import sys

for item in json.loads(sys.stdin.read()):
    print(item['name'])
```

But since I am very lazy, I am looking for a solution where I need to type less. For example in on the command line in a pipe:

```
curl https://example.com/get-json | MAGIC FILTER
```

I asked at [code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22139/46406) but they told me that it would make more sense to ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

```sh
% curl https://example.com/get-json | jq -r '.[].name'
NAME1
NAME2
```

- `-r` if the filter's result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes